# how to install 64-bit odbc by installshield in setup.rul?

Tags: installation, odbc, dsn, regedit, installshield-2012

```
//install 32-bit odbc dsn 
szFilePath="\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\"^szDemoDB;
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Database",REGDB_STRING, szDemoDB,-1); 
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Driver",REGDB_STRING, "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\sqlncli11.dll",-1);
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Server",REGDB_STRING,"(localdb)\\.\\v11.0",-1);
szFilePath="\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources";
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,szDemoDB,REGDB_STRING, "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",-1);
//install 64-bit odbc dsn 
szFilePath="\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\"^szDemoDB;
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Database",REGDB_STRING, szDemoDB,-1); 
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Driver",REGDB_STRING, "c:\Windows\System32\sqlncli11.dll",-1); 
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Server",REGDB_STRING,"(localdb)\\.\\v11.0",-1);
szFilePath="\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources";
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,szDemoDB,REGDB_STRING, "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",-1);
```

This is part code in `Setup.rul`. The top half is install 32-bit odbc dsn. It works well. I can see and use my 32-bit datasource in `regedit`.

The second half doesn't work. It confused me, I found the path `\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\` is invalid，the `RegDBSetKeyValueEx` always set value to path `\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTIONS | REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;

szFilePath="\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\"^szDemoDB;
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Database",REGDB_STRING, szDemoDB,-1); 
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Driver",REGDB_STRING, "c:\Windows\System32\sqlncli11.dll",-1); 
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,"Server",REGDB_STRING,"(localdb)\\.\\v11.0",-1);
szFilePath="\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources";
RegDBSetKeyValueEx(szFilePath,szDemoDB,REGDB_STRING, "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",-1);

REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTIONS & ~REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;
```